# Volume of solid generated by rotating $y=x^2$ about the $x$-axis from $x=1$ to $x=2$ using cylindrical shells

Tags: calculus

I am attempting to find the volume of the solid generated by rotating the function $ y=x^2 $ about the $x$-axis from $x=1$ to $x=2$ using cylindrical shells. Here is the integral that I am using:

$$
2\pi\int_{1}^{4} y(2 - \sqrt{y}) dy
$$

When I evaluate this integral, I get $\frac{26\pi}{5}$. This is different than the answer I get when using the washer method with the following integral:

$$
\pi\int_{1}^{2} x^4 dx
$$

When evaluating this integral, I get $\frac{31\pi}{5}$.

Why do I get different results when using the two different methods? Is there a problem with the way I set-up my first integral?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the difference between the volumes obtained by the washer and cylinder methods is exactly $$\frac{(31 - 26)\pi}{5} = \pi.$$

This volume corresponds to a cylinder whose axis is the $x$-axis, with a circular base of radius $1$, and height $1$.

The reason why the cylinder is counted in the washer integral is because a representative washer (which is actually a disk) has the full radius $x^2$, rather than a true annular washer with outer radius $x^2$ and inner radius $1$.  Since the problem is posed in a way that suggests *not* to exclude the interior cylinder, the correct answer is given by your washer method.

To correct the result obtained by cylindrical shells, you must account for the missing cylinder.  Note that when you integrate from $y = 1$ to $y = 4$, you're missing the volume from $y = 0$ to $y = 1$.  But you cannot write $$V = 2\pi \int_{y=0}^4 y (2 - \sqrt{y}) \, dy,$$ because this would also include the spindle-shaped region from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$ that you tried to exclude in the first place.  Instead, you would write
$$V = 2\pi \int_{y=1}^4 y (2 - \sqrt{y}) \, dy + 2\pi \int_{y=0}^1 y \, dy,$$ where the second integrand corresponds to a cylindrical shell with representative radius $y$, height $1$, and differential thickness $dy$.